# Unable to print PHP tags inside

Tags: php, html

I want to print PHP declaration tag `<?php ?>` inside HTML output using **echo**

For example my code is below:

```
$var = '<?php echo "hello world"; ?>';
echo $var;
```

But it gives me empty result, when I add something after the **$var** in echo as:

```
echo $var . "<b>hello world<b>";
```

This gives output:

```
hello world
```

But It should give result as `<?php echo "hello world" ?> Hello world`

How it can be possible?

Comment: With what character does a html tag starts? With what character does your string starts? Do you see html tags on the page? *hint, hint*

Comment: what does `echo htmlentities($var);` give you?

Comment: It gives me gas @mistermartin ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Oh, wait. Not that. Onions give me gas.

Comment: You need `&lt;` and `&gt;` to display `<` and `>`. Else, it will treat it as HTML tags. Either use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function or convert it to above said code.

Comment: Here read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score -1):

For browser it's just a html tag, because it starts with < and ends with >. Browser views it as invalid html tag and displays nothing.

Try using `echo htmlentities($var)."<b>hello world</b>";`

Comment: Best Guess: Could be because, people should know that basically, `<` and `>` are reserved characters in HTML, when learning HTML.

Comment: The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies. I wouldn't get too wound up about it and it is not my downvote. but if you ran your code you would know why.

Comment: That's the thing I hate when people just downvote without telling why. Tried running my code, everything works.

Comment: You're not likely to get answers @Rikudou_Sennin

Comment: thank you. this solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome :) If it helped, you can mark my answer as the solution :)